# tmux new-session will cause duplicate path entries

Tags: path, tmux, anaconda

I am using a Mac. When I `tmux new-session -s` will new a session with a window with duplicate `$PATH` entries in random order, which is different from these outside Tmux.

However if I `C-b c` to create a new window inside the same Tmux session, `$PATH` entries will be normal and correct again. I totally get lost and want to know how to debug this.

This will cause some of my script that I wrote for Tmux fail to execute. The script worked very well before but are not working now.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I find that tmux will always call the profile for your shell, not just the rc. So if you are using bash like I do, it will call /etc/profile, which will have a call to path_helper.

In order to fix this, change `/etc/profile` to:

```
if [[ -z $TMUX ]] && [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

If you are using bash, also change any `export PATH=$PATH:/foo` in `.bashrc` to

```
if [[ -z $TMUX ]]; then
  export PATH=$PATH:/foo
fi
```

then you restart the terminal(for example Iterm). Everything should be good!

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate env var keys, if their corresponding values are the same, are no reason for a script to fail.

Make your script deal with redundant information gracefully and to only abort if different values are coming for one same single key.

Comment: Thanks. You are right for most cases. But what my script do is actually to new a tmux session and activate a conda env automatically. With the duplicate and wrong order PATH, the `conda activate myenv` will fail to work. However if I `C-b c` to create a new window inside the same tmux session and `conda activate myenv`, then everything is fine.

Comment: I don't troubleshoot Anaconda. Once you got some other better answer, I'll remove this.

Comment: Maybe it's related to shell interactivity, the `bashrc` and the Bash user profile.